# why codeignater view loads all html code in response

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

i am trying load query data in a html page but is shows all html code in alert
this is my controller

```
public function Get_account_data_for_report(){
    if($this->session->userdata('user_login_access') != False) {
        $from_date=$this->input->post('date_from');
        $to_date=$this->input->post('date_to');
        $id=$this->input->post('acc_id');
        $data['report']=$this->Accounts_model->individual_acc($from_date,$to_date,$id);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }else{
        redirect(base_url() , 'refresh');
    }
}
```

This is my ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#getReport').click(function(){
      var date_from=$('#date_from').val();
        var date_to=$('#date_to').val();
        var acc_id=$('#acc_id').val();

            $.ajax({
                url:'Get_account_data_for_report',
                method:'POST',
                data: {
                    date_from: date_from,
                    date_to: date_to,
                    acc_id: acc_id
                }
            }).done(function(response) {
                alert(response);
                var data = JSON.parse(response);
            })
    })
});
```

And this is my html

```
<form  action="" class="form-material row" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date"  class="form-control mydatetimepickerFull" placeholder="from">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="text" id="to_date" name="to_date"  class="form-control mydatetimepickerFull" placeholder="to">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <select class="form-control custom-select"  tabindex="1" name="acc_id" id="acc_id"  required>
        <option>Account</option>
         <?php foreach($accounts as $k=>$v): ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $v->Accounts_id ?>">
            <?php echo $v->Account_Name ?>

         </option>
         <?php endforeach;  ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit" id="getReport">
```

even if i wrote direct in action also giving same error
and in console it showing all html code and

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}

readyState: 4
getResponseHeader: ƒ (a)
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
setRequestHeader: ƒ (a,b)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (a)
statusCode: ƒ (a)
abort: ƒ (a)
state: ƒ ()
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ (a)
pipe: ƒ ()
then: ƒ (b,d,e)
promise: ƒ (a)
progress: ƒ ()
done: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
```

Comment: Are you sending the AJAX request to the same page?

Comment: no this page has only one form

Answer (score 0):

I have never looked at `CodeIgniter` so might be wide of the mark with this but if the AJAX request is showing all the current page HTML in the response you need to dispose of any content being generated by anything other than your `Get_account_data_for_report` method. If one sends an ajax request to the same page I'd typically call `ob_clean()` before sending any data and explicitly terminate the response once the data is sent - to that end perhaps the following *might* help?!

```
public function Get_account_data_for_report(){
    ob_clean(); #discard any previous output from the buffers

    if( $this->session->userdata('user_login_access') != False ) {
        $from_date=$this->input->post('date_from');
        $to_date=$this->input->post('date_to');
        $id=$this->input->post('acc_id');
        $data['report']=$this->Accounts_model->individual_acc($from_date,$to_date,$id);

        #terminate response here
        exit( json_encode( $data ) );
    }else{
        redirect(base_url() , 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Also perhaps you could modify the jQuery function slightly:

```
$('#getReport').click(function(){....
```

to

```
$('#getReport').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); ....
```